# Confused with Bayesian parameter estimation and Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: bayesian

I'm confused with an example in MLE and Bayesian estimation.

It's about 'coin tossing', where we toss a coin n times, and the probability of observing head is theta. 'theta' is an unknown parameter in this case.

The textbook says, we denote **x** as :

**1 (when head),
0 (when tail)**

and **D** to be the sample set of all **x**s defined above.
then with **MLE** :

[MLE method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZXlh.png)

but with **Bayesian estimation** on the same problem, (It says, with p(theta) = theta(1-theta))

[Bayesian method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxlMH.png)

How is the solution in the Bayesian method possible (theta_hat is a fixed value)? What I learnt was, the estimated parameter theta_hat would be **a fixed value** in MLE estimation, but in Bayesian estimation, the estimated parameter would be **a random variable and is not a fixed value.** Also, I don't get that the estimated parameter is derived by solving the gradient equation = 0. How is this possible?

Comment: "Bayesian estimation" is a somewhat imprecise term.  There is "maximum a-posteriori estimation" and "posterior mean estimation".  Your book seems to use the former.  Does your textbook give a precise statement of what Bayesian estimation is?